# push_back in a vector in a object

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, push-back

I have a profesor class with this atribute

```
vector<int> hDisponibles;
```

If I have a vector of this class

```
set<profesor> profesores;
```

I try this

```
set<profesor>::iterator itP;
itP = profesores.begin();    
while ( itP != profesores.end() ){                
    (*itP).hDisponibles->push_back(0);                                                    
    itP++;
}
```

but this errors

```
utils.cpp:138: error: passing ‘const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >’ as ‘this’     argument of ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]’ discards qualifiers
```

Comment: What errors? What's `hDisponibles`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the `vector` you are trying to call `push_back` on is `const`. This is because (since C++11) the elements of a `std::set` are accessed through `const_iterators`, since changing them might change how they compare and therefore corrupt the `set`. To solve that you have two options:

1. If `hDisponibles` has no effect on how `profesor` compare and it doesn't do to much damage to your overall structure you can declare it `mutable` like this: `mutable vector<int> hDisponibles;`. `mutable` members can be changed even if the structure they reside in is `const`
2. I that is not an option, you have to remove the `profesor` from the set (into a temporary), do your `push_back` and reinsert it (be careful about iterator invalidation). Of course this is quite costly.

Your code as posted has an additional bug, since `hdisponsibles` is an object, but `push_back` is called as if it was a pointer. From your compilermessage it doesn't seem like that bug is in your actual code, but just in case it should be:

```
(*itP).hDisponibles.push_back(0);
```

**Edit:** Found the section in the standard draft (the value type is the same as the key for `set` and `multiset`: N3290 §23.2.4/6

> iterator of an associative container is of the bidirectional iterator
>   category. For associative containers where  the value type is the same
>   as the key type, both iterator and const_iterator are constant
>   iterators. It is unspeciﬁed whether or not iterator and const_iterator
>   are the same type. [Note: iterator and const_iterator have identical
>   semantics in this case, and iterator is convertible to const_iterator.
>   Users can avoid violating the One Deﬁnition Rule by always using
>   const_iterator in their function parameter lists. —endnote ]

Comment: Or instead of (2), you could rewrite the whole loop, so that you build a completely new set of the modified results.

Comment: Alternatively, if hDisponibles were a pointer, then one wouldn't have to worry about the const/mutable stuff (as long as it isn't a pointer-to-const)

Answer (score 4):

`std::set` only offers const iterators, because modifying the objects while they're in the set would break set invariant. So, you can't do what you want with `std::set`, you need to either readd the new object, or use a different container.

Comment: Well, it's `std::vector`, so it's not const.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious error with your code is that you're using `->` instead of `.` on this line:

```
(*itP).hDisponibles->push_back(0);  // should be itP->hDisponibles.push_back(0);
```

But I have a feeling there are more errors related to syntax somewhere.  Please post a more complete summary of the code and the errors you're getting.

Comment: with (*itP).hDisponibles->push_back(0)    
error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >’